# Auto height doesn't work

Tags: css

I'm trying to get this thing to work on my website without any luck. The height of my `gray_content` box doesn't want to adjust automatically based on the content inside it: http://jsfiddle.net/w8Bn5/2/

CSS:

```
 .gray_content {
    height: auto;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 -21px -21px -21px;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset  0  2px 2px -2px #696868, 
                        inset  0 -2px 2px -2px #696868;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset  0  2px 2px -2px #696868, 
                        inset  0 -2px 2px -2px #696868;
     box-shadow:        inset  0  2px 2px -2px #696868, 
                        inset  0 -2px 2px -2px #696868;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
 }
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 29px;
  line-height: 29px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-left: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
ul.tabs li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555555;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
  background: #fff;
}  
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-top: none;
  clear: both;
  float: left; 
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}
.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gray_content">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            Content
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            Content
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            Content
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to add `overflow: auto`

Answer (score 1):

You can add `overflow:auto;` in your `.gray_content {}`  Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w8Bn5/4/)